# Scroll to div on link click

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, scroll

There are questions all over SO about this topic, but I've tried a ton of different scripts for this and I cannot get it to work with my site.

I am building a personal portfolio wordpress theme for myself, and would like to keep it a one page theme. What I want is when a user clicks a link on the navigation, the page scrolls down to that section. Easy right? No.

I don't know why it isn't working on my site, but I think it has to do with the script I am using for the scroll to fixed navigation.

Here is the script I am currently attempting to use to create this in-page navigation scrolling effect: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

And here is the script I am using to create the scroll to fixed navigation effect:

```
window.onscroll=function () {
    var top = window.pageXOffset ? window.pageXOffset : document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop;
    if(top > 640){
        document.getElementById("nav").style.position = "fixed";
        document.getElementById("nav").style.height="65px";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("nav").style.position = "relative";
        document.getElementById("nav").style.height="65px";
    }
}
```

You can view the site I am trying to do this on at http://www.tylerb.me

Are the two scripts contradicting each other and making one of them not work?

Comment: It appears to be working fine for me, what specifically is 'not working'?

Comment: did you click the link I provided to the site? You can see what is not working there.

Comment: It works on the site you linked to for me - it just drops you to below the title and gives you the actual paragraph you are looking for.

Comment: I need it to scroll @Jon. Please read my question.

Comment: @TyBailey I clicked the link at the end of this question; the link to your site.  It works fine for me; what are you testing this on?

Comment: You did not specify the problem

Comment: @TyBailey I did read the question... and it is working for me.

Comment: @TyBailey I see now, you want to animate the scrolling.

Comment: @Daedalus Yes, that is the problem.

Why the down vote? I clearly stated what the problem is. "What I want is when a user clicks a link on the navigation, the page scrolls down to that section. Easy right? No."

Comment: @TyBailey I didn't downvote you.  Maybe it wasn't clear for them.

Comment: @Daedalus, I know you didn't I didn't mean for that to be directed towards you. I was asking the others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear wordpress uses the `jQuery.noConflict()` method to prevent well.. conflicts from occurring.  Because of the script conflicts(moo tools uses $ as well, for example), replace each `$` with `jQuery`.  This should fix your issue.. and I do mean in the code which calls the plugin, not the plugin itself.

Example:

```
//normal jquery method call:
$("element").method(etc);

//with noConflict code:
jQuery("element").method(etc);
```

**UPDATE 1:**

It would appear that you forgot to leave a particular `$` alone.  This line:

```
var target = jQuery(this.hash), target = this.hash;
```

Should be this:

```
var $target = jQuery(this.hash), target = this.hash;
```

This of course goes with any variable that begins with a `$`.  Those ones should not be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

The core of your issue is that jQuery is not loading.

[image]

Daedalus just got there before me. It's no conflict that's causing your issue. Just use jQuery rather than $.

Comment: unfortunately, after replacing all the `$` with `jQuery` it still does not work. The error I am getting now is "Uncaught TypeError: Object #about has no method 'offset'"

Comment: Yes, it doesn't seem to be initialising the jQuery object of target, it's getting the Plain Old JavaScript object in place.

Shouldn't this line read: var target = jQuery(this.hash) || target = this.hash; ?? instead of the comma?

Answer (score 0):

This could prove useful to some.

Try using:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // do stuff here using $
});
```

instead of

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    // do stuff here
});
```

This declares a local $ instead of conflicting with the previously declared.

It helped me lots of times.